# XSRF Check Failed on Jira Server

Tags: angular, post, http-headers, http-status-code-403, jira-rest-api

I am trying to call a `POST` (also tried a `DELETE` method) method of a Jira server rest api from an angular application. Unfortunately, I am getting `403` error and it's saying `XSRF check failed`

[image]

I tried adding `X-Atlassian-Token: no-check` but it does not do the trick for me. Also I tried replacing the header's value of `'User-agent'` with a dummy one but I am getting

[image]

Here is the header

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json')
                               .set('X-Atlassian-Token','no-check')
                               .set('User-Agent','XX')
                               .append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.loginModel.username + ":" + this.loginModel.password));
```

I am getting completely frustrated because of this. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found to this problem is that you need to add an origin header that matches the domain that you are sending the request to. For example, if you are using Postman to send a request to https://foobar.example/ then set the Origin header to https://foobar.example/. then it should work. You can find some information about it here https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-protection-changes-in-atlassian-rest-779294918.html

Comment: I am using a 'proxy.config.json' for this. it's as follows:
{
    "/rest": {
        "target": "https://jira.abc.com/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

Can you tell me what to do. Still facing the same

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible to call protected APIs from third party websites as this would pose a security risk.

[Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/xsrf-check-failed-when-calling-cloud-apis-826874382.html)